# C# How can I display a list of objects like:

Tags: c#, list

I am trying to display a list of two subclasses of a parent class:

```
List<Geschenk> GeschenkListe = new List<Geschenk>
{
    new GeschenkKom(1,"PC-Spiel The Moment Of Silence","House Of Tales"),
    new GeschenkKom(2, "PC-Spiel Syndicate", "BullFrog"),
    new GeschenkKom(3, "PC-Spiel Syndicate Wars", "BullFrog"),
    new GeschenkKom(4, "PC-Spiel The Longest Journey", "FunCom"),
    new GeschenkKom(5, "PC-Spiel The Longest Journey: Dreamfall", "FunCom"),
    new GeschenkBas(6, "Weihnachtsstern", 1),
    new GeschenkBas(7, "Etui", 2),
    new GeschenkBas(9, "Weihnachtspyramide", 3),
    new GeschenkBas(10, "Kalender", 1)
};
GeschenkListe.Add(new GeschenkKom(11, "PC-Spiel The Moment Of Silence", "House Of Tales"));
```

I know what I created but I don't know how it is named correctly or how I can output it. I tried:

```
foreach(Object f in Geschenkliste)
{
    Geschenkliste(f).Ausgeben();
}
```

I tried it with Geschenk instead of Object to no avail.
Geschenk is the parent class of GeschnekKom and GeschenkBas.
Can anybody help me?

Comment: You're casting each element in the list to an object.  Why?  It's a list of `Geschenk`.

Comment: Just do: 
foreach(var item in Geschenkliste)
{
    item.Ausgeben();
}

Answer (score 7):

You could try this:

```
foreach(var item in Geschenkliste)
{
    item.Ausgeben();
}
```

As it can be inferred from your code, you just try to call a method called `Ausgeben` on each object in the `Geschenkliste`. So by using the `foreach` statement like above you can do so. You declare implicitly (using the `var` keyword) the type of `item`. At the compile time this would be replaced with `Geschenk`, which is the type of the items whose references are stored in the list. In other words the above `foreach` statement is equivalent to the following one:

```
foreach(Geschenk item in Geschenkliste)
{
    item.Ausgeben();
}
```

> Why by declaring as the type of `item` the `Object` class this cannot work?

Because the method `Ausgeben` is defined on the class `Geschenk` and not on the `System.Object`, which is the base class of all types in .NET Framework ([Object](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.object(v=vs.110).aspx)).

Comment: Maybe mention why your code actually fixes the problem (i.e `var item`  vs `object f`)